# shuffling collection and Cannot understand how to translate NewGuid()

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

I have following query

```
 var nrOfRetrievedDocs = new List<RetrievedDocs>().Count();
 _docs= RavenSession.Query<DocsToProcess>().Skip(nrOfRetrievedDocs)
          .OrderBy(x=>Guid.NewGuid()).Take(1024).ToList();
```

I'm getting

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Raven.Client.Lightweight.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot understand how to translate NewGuid()

I want to shuffle collection and select 1024 objects on random position.

Why I'm gettng this `Cannot understand how to translate NewGuid()` and how to overcome this, is there a better (faster) way to select random items inside collection?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but won't this line `var nrOfRetrievedDocs = new List<RetrievedDocs>().Count();` **always** be 0?

Comment: You are using some kind of entity based framework. I don't think it will be very easy to get a random subset from it.

Comment: I think `OrderBy` is going to work on a property of the object in the collection; by trying to order by a value that isn't part of the object(s) in the collection the mapper is probably getting confused.  It doesn't know what to compare/assign `Guid.NewGuid()` to.  That's just a semi-educated guess though.

Comment: @Tim in this example yes :) Typed typo in a hurry. You get the point. That statement should return int of retrieved documents.

Comment: All frameworks that supply there own IQuerable implementation for SQL doing the same. They are reading you Expression in your case Guid.NewGuid and then they try to Convert the expression to SQL. Thats all of the Magic. For example the Skip expression accepts a Constant or a Variable. When executing the framework will resolve this expression to an SQL conform Skip. The same with take all of this LinqExpressions are only converted to SQL that is all. And for SQL there is not conversion allowed that takes a Guid paramter inside an OrderBy clausel.

Comment: Please don't assume Guids are random. They might be, but there is no guarantee. You should use a proper random number generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do random ordering, you can do that directly, instead of like this:

http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/session/querying/how-to-customize-query#randomordering

```
List<Employee> results = session.Query<Employee>()
    .Customize(x => x.RandomOrdering())
    .Where(x => x.FirstName == "Robert")
    .ToList();
```